# Docker image Prune Filtering

Tags: docker

Currently I am running

```
while true; do
    docker system prune --all -f;
    sleep 6400;
    done
```

In a daemonset to remove older images in my containers.

There is some unused images that I still want to keep around. Is there a possibility to filter out some images to not be pruned by this command?

for example after running docker system prune command,the following should not change if I want to prune everything else except repository a

```
Repository         TAG          IMAGE_ID         CREATED     SIZE
a                  12dac         3eadf            now          1
a                  44rfd         233df            4 month ago  1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can add regular expression filters to prevent certain containers from pruning.

```
filtered=$(docker image prune –filter name=foo* -aq)
docker rm $filtered
```

This will delete all except containers that begin with the letters `foo`.

If necessary, you can read about the additional keys you can use for filtering in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/)

(2022) Update: This is no longer supported. Please see the other answers.

Comment: what should I do to prevent InitContainers to be pruned?

Comment: @Kenrosh Can you expand? They are also containers correct. Is it not possible to filter them also?

Comment: docker 19.03 doesn't seem to accept name= as a filter: "Error response from daemon: Invalid filter 'name'"

Comment: The command above fails with `Error response from daemon: Invalid filter 'name'`

Comment: The only supported filters are `until` and `label` according to the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/#filtering).

Answer (score 3):

```
docker images --format "{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}:{{.ID}}" | grep "what_you_need" | cut -f 3 -d ":" | xargs docker rmi
```

works for single "what_you_need" image. Look at the example:

```
docker images --format "{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}:{{.ID}}" | grep "prom/prometheus:v2.32.1" | cut -f 3 -d ":" | xargs docker rmi
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs on filter](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/#filtering), adding a label to the bottom of your docker image will allow you to group your images.

For example, you could **create a label in your dockerfile** called `storage` and set its value to `do_not_delete` for the images you want to keep:

```
LABEL storage="do_not_delete"
```

Then **run `docker build ...`** to apply this label to the image.

Now, **in your script**, you can prune all images where the label `storage` isn't explicitly set to `do_not_delete`. Here is a sample command:

```
docker image prune --all -f --filter label!=storage="do_not_delete"
```

**EXTRA**
We can chain these filters too. In this example we prune all images older than one hour, while respecting the `do_not_delete` label:

```
docker image prune --all -f --filter label!=storage="do_not_delete" --filter until=1h
```

This can also be useful for clean up images you're actively developing against and/or testing. I use the command below to remove clutter in my dev environment:

```
# assuming all the images I'm working against have this line
LABEL env="scratch"

docker image prune --all --filter label=env="scratch"  --filter until=1h
```